# Send Null Byte?

Tags: python, encoding, binary, system

Is it possible to send null byte through internet so that the other side can read it properly without truncation at null byte position?

For example:

str = "\xab\xcd\x00\x12\xf6\xbe"

The other side can only read \xab\xcd now.

Comment: In general that is possible. But there might be limitations of the protocol (which you did not specify) and the other side's implementation.

Comment: Are you sure the other end doesn't receive it? The error could be in printing out what it receives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, the task is trivial, **if** the server is receiving binary data correctly.  For example, server side:

```
from socket import *
serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
serverSocket.bind(('', 12000))

while True:
    message, address = serverSocket.recvfrom(1024)
    print 'Server received', repr(message)
    serverSocket.sendto(message + message, address)
```

and client side

```
from socket import *
message = '\xab\xcd\x00\x12\xf6\xbe'
clientSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM)
clientSocket.sendto(message, ('127.0.0.1', 12000))
data, server = clientSocket.recvfrom(1024)
print 'client received:', repr(data)
```

shows it working perfectly (running client and server on two terminals on the same machine, given the IP address I'm using here:-).